# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060007 type #0x12 is not valid

Tags: android

Ao terminar de criar uma listFragment e chama-la no main o apk encerra dando o erro abaixo:
[image: erro]

Aqui esta minha ListFragment:

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
SimpleAdapter adapter;
String[] atividades = new String[]{"item1", "item2", "item3"};
int[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.imagem1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
  };

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < atividades.length; i++) {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("atividade", atividades[i]);
        map.put("imagem", Integer.toString(imageId[i]));
        data.add(map);
    }
    String[] from = {"atividade", "imageId"};
    int[] to = {R.id.txt, R.id.img};
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.id.listView, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

e minha classe main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No   `SimpleAdapter` , deve se passar um **layout**, não um **id**:

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.id.listView, from, to);
```

Para corrigir:

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.layout.layout_da_lista, from, to);
```